before he started working for you
a. He had worked for us before he started working for you.
I can see three possibilities:

He started working for you right after he stopped working for us.

There was a time lapse between the time he stopped working for us and he started working for you.

He kept on working for us after he started working for you.


Which of the cases 1-3 can correspond to (a)?
Many thanks

One question at a time, please!

Thank you, Michael. I edited my question,

All of 1, 2, and 3 could be true, given (a). To convey more exact information, you have to be more exact.
